# Terraform separate input variables via IF statement according to values of another input variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-opensearch

I have two elasticsearch services managed with terraform. But one version is 6.8 while the other is 7.10 . The problem is that I had to describe the `ebs_option` input variable because of the instance size that I am using. However, when I run the `terraform plan` command after describing this, I get the following output:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.aws-opensearch.aws_elasticsearch_domain.elastic-domains[1] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "elastic-domains" {
        id                    = "arn:aws:es:eu-central-1:xxx:domain/new-elastic"
        tags                  = {
            "Environment" = "test"
            "Name"        = "new-elastic"
            "Namespace"   = "test"
        }
        # (9 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ ebs_options {
          - iops        = 3000 -> null
            # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)
        }

        # (13 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

**Even though I apply it, I get the same output every time I run the `terraform apply` command.**
When I researched this a bit, when elasticsearch is version 7.10, it uses gp3 storage. But in version 6.8 it uses gp2. There are some differences between the two that come by default. `iops` is one of them.

How can I overcome this problem? Since I defined it under a single module, I cannot give it separately.

I have terraform configuration below:

main.tf

```
resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "elastic-domains" {

  count = length(var.domain_names)

  domain_name           = var.domain_names[count.index].domain_name
  elasticsearch_version = var.domain_names[count.index].elasticsearch_version

  ...

  ebs_options {
    ebs_enabled = true
    volume_size = 50
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable domain_names {
    type=list(object({
        domain_name           = string
        elasticsearch_version = number
    }))
}
```

terraform.tfvars

```
domain_names = [
    {
        domain_name           = "elastic"
        elasticsearch_version = "6.8"
    },
    {
        domain_name           = "new-elastic"
        elasticsearch_version = "7.10"
    }    
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You conditionally set the iops to `null` depending on the version. E.g.

```
ebs_options {
    ebs_enabled = true
    volume_size = 50
    iops = startswith(var.domain_names[count.index].elasticsearch_version, "7") ? 3000 : null
}
```